# Has anybody ever worked with KDE inc. (EDM-4000 series) devices?

Tags: embedded, smartcard, emv

Has anybody ever worked with **KDE inc.** (EDM-4000 series) devices? Or with devices of "neighbor" series like KDM-47XY, KDM-57XY, etc.? EDM-4000 series (if exactly, my particular device is **EDM-4954** VER :X1.01) is a motorized insertion type of MS & IC card Reader/Writer module with RS-232C interface for enterprise customers like banks. My problem is that I cannot get a successful **ATR** form the card, on power ON.
I send commands sequentially **INIT - GET VERSION - ENTRY - STATUS REQUEST - IC POWER ON...** But always receive status **IC CARD NO ATR:**

```
0X02 0X4E 0X38 0X31 0X31 0X33 0X03 0X46 0X0D
STX  'N'  cm    pm  err0 err1  ETX  BCC  CR
```

0X31 0X33 err status means **IC CARD NO ATR**

Here is the full flow:

```
Opening port: /dev/ttyUSB0
0X02 0X43 0X30 0X30 0X33 0X32 0X34 0X30 0X33 0X30 0X30 0X30 0X30 0X31 0X30 0X03 0X77 0X0D 
write INIT
2022/11/23 14:04:12 Write bytes: 18
Read attempt: 0
Start reader
Received:0X06 0X0D 
reader: got data
2022/11/23 14:04:13 ACK received
write ENQ
2022/11/23 14:04:13 Write bytes: 2
Start reader
Received:0X02 0X50 0X30 0X30 0X30 0X31 0X32 0X32 0X32 0X31 0X32 0X03 0X63 0X0D 
reader: got data
22212
INIT answer code is P ...OK
Track1: RW
Track2: RW
Track3: RW
JIS: RW
Support ICC: ICC able
0X02 0X43 0X3C 0X30 0X03 0X4C 0X0D 
write get version type
2022/11/23 14:04:14 Write bytes: 7
Read attempt: 0
Start reader
Received:0X06 0X0D 
reader: got data
2022/11/23 14:04:14 ACK received
write ENQ
2022/11/23 14:04:14 Write bytes: 2
Read attempt: 0
Start reader
Received:0X02 0X50 0X3C 0X30 0X30 0X31 0X28 0X20 0X45 0X44 0X4D 0X2D 0X34 0X39 0X35 0X34 0X20 0X56 0X45 0X52 0X20 0X3A 0X58 0X31 0X2E 0X30 0X31 0X20 0X29 0X03 0X0F 0X0D 
reader: got data
( EDM-4954 VER :X1.01 )
0X02 0X43 0X32 0X31 0X03 0X43 0X0D 
PLEASE INSERT A CARD AND PRESS A KEY
I got the byte [32] ( )
write ENTRY
2022/11/23 14:04:15 Write bytes: 7
Read attempt: 0
Start reader
Received:0X06 0X0D 
reader: got data
2022/11/23 14:04:15 ACK received
write ENQ
2022/11/23 14:04:16 Write bytes: 2
Start reader
Received:0X02 0X50 0X32 0X31 0X30 0X32 0X03 0X52 0X0D 
reader: got data

0X02 0X43 0X31 0X31 0X03 0X40 0X0D 
write STATUS REQUEST /get char
I got the byte [32] ( )
2022/11/23 14:04:19 Write bytes: 7
Read attempt: 0
Start reader
Received:0X06 0X0D 
reader: got data
2022/11/23 14:04:19 ACK received
write ENQ
2022/11/23 14:04:20 Write bytes: 2
Read attempt: 0
Start reader
Received:0X02 0X50 0X31 0X31 0X30 0X32 0X42 0X48 0X03 0X5B 0X0D 
reader: got data
BH
0X02 0X43 0X38 0X31 0X03 0X49 0X0D 
write IC POWER ON /get char
2022/11/23 14:04:20 Write bytes: 7
Read attempt: 0
Start reader
Received:0X06 0X0D 
reader: got data
2022/11/23 14:04:20 ACK received
write ENQ
2022/11/23 14:04:20 Write bytes: 2
Start reader
Received:0X02 0X4E 0X38 0X31 0X31 0X33 0X03 0X46 0X0D
```

Unfortunately, such a behavior I have with all the IC cards I have, of various payment systems. What am I doing wrong? Or might my device be not OK? Cannot find any example, or community in the internet about these devices. Vendor also gives very few manuals. Might anybody have worked with this vendor? I work fine with a magnetic stripe, but I need ICC EMV mode now.

Comment: I'm not posting that as an answer as I don't have any experience with this particular device. My suggestion though is to check if your issue is not generated by libusb and polling on the bus that it is doing. Some devices (and ATM motorized readers I have worked with in particular) have issues with the timings that are used by libusb default settings. I have seen situations that card reset or APDU exchange commands were not executing properly when libusb was used to communicate to other devices on the bus and worked normally when libusb was deactivated.

Comment: I am sure somebody has! It is an odd question to ask, and I am not sure how it helps you.  Your question should be about your problem, not about whether the device is "used" by any one.  Moreover I n any case, your question is not clearly on-topic, it appears to be about operation of a third party device, not about your code development, or even any code development. Ask the vendor's support.  They will certainly have "used" this device